# How do you use heap snapshots from the Chrome profiler to hunt for memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, profiler

I seriously don't know how to use the information shown here in the heap snapshot to hunt down whatever is using so much memory in my application. I understand that when I click on one particular item in the top view window, it's hierarchical property ownership/references are shown down below in the bottom window in the collapsable tree. But that's it. I have the vague sense that whatever the issue is, it has something to do with the file sc2_env.js in my project but I have no idea where to go from there.

[image: Heap snapshot comparison between two snapshots]

Any suggestions on how to better navigate these heap snapshots would be greatly appreciated!

For anyone who's interested I've linked the heap snapshot file [here](https://github.com/arcman7/jssc2/blob/bin/agent/bin/Heap-20200915T160055.heaptimeline)

Comment: (after 3.5 years, I know) did you manage to find helpful references on how to interpret those reports?

Answer (score 1):

For Example, the thing you want to dive into here in sc2_env.js file is line 112 (maybe on the compiled file on the server you took the snapshot and then move onward to the file on your local).
Keep that in mind and analyze the others leak and you are on to fix those memory leaks.

Comment: but line 112 of that file is just where the constructor of the SC2Env class starts. I don't get how that's useful. What is the implied hint?

Comment: You should check the file on the Sources tab not the one on your local dev.

Comment: It's exactly the same in the sources panel; line 112 of sc2_env.js is still just the beginning of the constructor of the SC2Env class

Comment: Maybe the object is not probably disposed or something. You might want to check with your team to  fig into it.